# Get url parameter in a class based form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I’m using a class based form and view.  The user selects a company from the 'choose company form' and then adds contacts to the company on the 'create contacts for company form'. Given that the company is known, the company select list should not appear on the 'create contacts for company form' because it is long and the user should not be able to change the company on the 'create contacts for company form'.

Question1: To avoid showing the company list, I have set the company widget to a hidden in forms.py.  However, I do know how to set the initial value of the hidden field to the url parameter.

Question2: There is an obvious weakness with this method as the user can change the companyid in the url or the hidden value in the form.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
Urls.py
    url(r'^company/contact/create/(?P<companyid>\d*)/$', contact_create.as_view(), name='contact-create')

Models.py
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

forms.py
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        widgets = {
            'company' : HiddenInput(attrs={ 'initial': <GET URL PARAM COMPANYID>})
        }

view.py
class contact_create(CreateView):
    model = Contact
    form_class = ContactForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form Meta class is evaluated at import time, so naturally won't have access to the initial data. If you wanted to set that, you would do it in the view, by overriding the [`get_initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) method.

(Note by the way that a widget doesn't have an initial attribute, as initial is a property of the field, not the widget.)

However, as you say, this is not a good way doing things, as the value of a hidden input can be changed. You want to set this value explicitly - again, do it in the view, this time in the [`form_valid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) method.

It would look something like this:

```
class ContactCreate(CreateView):
    model = Contact
    form_class = ContactForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        contact = form.save(commit=False)
        contact.company_id = self.kwargs['company']
        contact.save()
        self.object = contact
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: changed self.kwargs['company'] to self.kwargs['companyid']